# python libvirt ESX Driver error File .vmdk was not found

Tags: python, vsphere, libvirt, esxi

I am trying to create a virtual machine on vmware vSphere 6.0 using python, libvirt 1.2.19. I am connecting and creating new VM (it appears in the vSphere client), but it cannot be started because of the exception below.

```
libvirt: ESX Driver error : internal error: Could not start domain:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/three/Downloads/py_scripts/ppp.py", line 129, in <module>
    if dom.create() < 0:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 866, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: Could not start domain:
FileNotFound - File /vmfs/volumes/55f98248-00c1a741-e340-000c29b1c8a3/vtest/vtest.vmdk was not found
```

Folder of this VM on the ESXi server contains 3 files: vtest.vmx, vtest.vmsd and vtest.log.
Here is the xml config I use to create this domain:

```
<domain type='vmware'>
  <name>vtest</name>
  <uuid>cc0a4d56-27bf-82d4-c0a7-ada003b1c8a3</uuid>
  <memory>409600</memory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <source file='[datastore1] vtest/vtest.vmdk'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <source file='[datastore1] isos/lubuntu.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='lsilogic'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'/>    
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:50:56:91:48:c7'/>
      <source bridge='VM Network'/>
    </interface>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> Folder of this VM on the ESXi server contains 3 files: vtest.vmx, vtest.vmsd and vtest.log. Here is the xml config I use to create this domain:

You are trying to find `vtest/vtest.vmdk` which is simply not present.

Create the .vmdk file and try again.